# How to know the number of lines in a file without loading its content to the memory in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, filesystems, large-files

**Brief:**
A system that will load CSV files, but they are expected to be **huge** (+1M lines). I already have a idea on how to process them using queues and background jobs/tasks.

**But,**
I want to display to the user a progress on his file, something line: *2165 of 1246875* or maybe the percentage of it. To archive this, I need to know the number of lines in the file, but I have to to this without loading its contents to the memory, so it can be fast, as soon as I got an upload and can save the filename within the total lines founds in it.

**In PHP this is possible** using `SplFileObject` trying to `seek()` to the `PHP_MAX_INT`, then it goes to the highest line it can in the file and `key()` returns that line.

But the system is being built entirely in JavaScript/Node.js so, just for convenience, I want to build this system part in JavaScript as well.

**How could I accomplish that?** Already took a look at [FS API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), but didn't find how to to this.

**[EDIT]**
Ideas so far:

1. `child_process.exec` + `wc -l` (Unix only)
2. Get this info from the client using `FileReader` (Delegate resources to the user)

Comment: You can read some first rows, calc avg size of row and divide filesize on it.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but if you read the file async and don't specify a file encoding, you handle just the chunks, right?  So could you count the line breaks in each chunk and let the chunk get garbage collected?

Comment: You don't need to count the lines. Keep track of the number of processed bytes and divide it by the file length to know how much of the file you already processed. Multiply by 100 to express it as percentage.

Answer (score 2):

**This is impossible.**

Lines are a human concept about a file. For computers, files are just a bunch of bytes; you can know the total bytes, you can seek thought bytes length, but knowing how much lines does this bytes have envolves counting line breaks and counting line breaks envolves reading them.

Both `wc` and PHP's `SplFileObject` streams the entire file, they don't do magic. So the best answer is which method does this in most efficient way. Which means, what GC would operate better.

On the other hand, if accuracy is not a requirement, you can try to guess. If all lines have a fixed bytes length, you can divide it by the total bytes of the file. Or, as [pointed by Aikon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491603/how-to-know-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-without-loading-its-content-to-the-mem#comment77944854_45491603), you can read just a few bytes (them break into lines) get the average length of them and divide by the total bytes of the file.

Although it is bringing file content to the memory, [Joel Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483513/joel-lord) answer is the answer for a Node.js solution. You can also take a look at [readline module](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

Comment: *knowing how much lines does this bytes have envolves counting line breaks* Exactly.  You can also think of "counting lines" as actually "counting newline characters" (calling them "line breaks" might be confusing to some), because that's what defines a "line".  And to *count* newline characters, you have to find *all* of them.  Which means reading the *entire* file.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a stream as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

The following example should could the number of lines in a file, using the first argument as the file name.

ie: 
node countlines.js nameoffiletocountthelines.csv

```
var fs = require("fs");

var lines = 0;
//Using the first argument as the filename
var filename = process.argv[2];

var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename)

//When data is received, check all the character codes and
//if we find a carriage return, increment the line counter
stream.on("data", function(chunk) {
    for(var i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) {
        if (chunk[i] == 10 || chunk[i] == 13) lines++;
    }
});

//When the file processing is done, echo the number of lines
stream.on("end", function() {
    console.log("Lines: " + lines);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seams that this doesn't prevent file content from being added to the memory. I tested with a 134.091.524 bytes CSV and Node's `process.memoryUsage()` reported 106.373.180 bytes of external usage.